# JPA, put complex data type inside an entity in the same table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a class Customer which is an entity:
@Entity

```
public class Customer {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="customerId_Sequence")
@SequenceGenerator(name="customerId_Sequence",sequenceName="CUSTOMER_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
private long customerId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName; 
private BillingDetails billingDetails
```

I have a class BillingDetails that looks like this:

```
public class BillingDetails {
private String type;
private long ccNumber;
```

I use hibernate as my persistence provider. I want it to create just one table in sql, which have columns customerId, firstName, lastName, type, ccNumber. I want it all in one table, I don't want billing details to be an entity. Is this possible?

When I try like this I get an error: Could not determine type for: ****.BillingDetails

Answer (score 2):

Model BillingDetails as @Embeddable.

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="customerId_Sequence")
@SequenceGenerator(name="customerId_Sequence",sequenceName="CUSTOMER_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
private long customerId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName; 

@Embedded
private BillingDetails billingDetails;
...
}



@Embeddable
public class BillingDetails {
private String type;
private long ccNumber;
...
}
```